# Existence of expected value with complex power

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $X$ be a random variable taking values on $(0,+\infty)$ with density function $f(x)$ and we have $\mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$. Can we conclude that $$\mathbb{E}(X^{-2-it}) <\infty,\quad\quad (1)$$ 
where $i$ is the imaginary unit, $i^2 =-1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I did a computation: for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\mathbb{E}(X^{-2-it}) = \int x^{-2-it}f(x)dx=\int x^{-2}f(x)\left(\cos(t\log(x)) - i\sin(t\log(x))  \right)dx \\
= \int x^{-2}f(x)\cos(t\log(x))dx -i\int x^{-2}f(x)\sin(t\log(x))dx$$

Since $\cos(t\log(x))$ and $\sin(t\log(x))$ are bounded by $1$. Can we deduce that $(1)$ is true and from Strong Law of Large Numbers, can we have?
$$ \mathbb{E}(X^{-2-it}) \longrightarrow \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{-2-it}\quad \text{a.s}\quad\quad (2)$$
where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with density $f(x)$. Thanks for your answers or comments.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you take $$f_X (u) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ for } u\notin [0,1] \\ 1 \mbox{ for } u\in [0,1]\end{cases}$$
then $$\mathbb{E} (X^2 ) =\frac{1}{3}<\infty$$
but $$\mbox{Re}\left(\mathbb{E} (X^{-2-it})\right) =\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-s}\cos(ts) ds =\infty .$$

Comment: @ FisaiLusia: thank you. So, by your answer, we must need an assumption $\mathbb{E}(X^{-2})<\infty$ to make $X$ satisfy $(1)$.